# library to create static maps (an image) with custom map features

Tags: python, openstreetmap, web-mapping, java, tile-map-service

Do you know if there is a small library (preferably in python or java) around that allows the creation of static maps? Something where you can specific the URL of your TMS server, width and height in pixel, and a simple geometry (point or linestring) to be drawn on top?

I found [staticmaplite](https://github.com/dfacts/staticmaplite) in the [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Static_map_images) which is acutally a very good starting point, but we do not support php in our stack.

Do you know any other projects in python / java that are available. Otherwise I will consider creating a clone of staticmaplite in python. But it would be better to build on something already available.

Comment: Are Leaflet or OpenLayers (both JavaScript) an option?

Comment: That would be a natural choice, but since I plan to use it also for Facebook previews I need a real image.

Answer (score 4):

If your interested in using a microservice that you can run yourself, instead of a library check out https://github.com/trailbehind/StaticMapService/. You can install background layers into it, then post GeoJSON and get back map images. You mentioned facebook preview images, and that's exactly what I wrote it for. The image url points at a public web server, which requests the map images from the map renderer running on a private network, and caches the images.

Comment: Great service @jesse-crocker ! If your answer would have reached me earlier I would not have started building a small library by my own: https://github.com/komoot/staticmap

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime I created a small python-based library that can create simple static images. You can find it on github: https://github.com/komoot/staticmap

Comment: This is still far better than other options that exist in 2024. Thank you for creating it.